# Extracting the T Statistic from a function in R

Tags: r

I have this function that I got from a textbook that runs a couple of linear regressions and then saves the P-Value for each regression.

I would also like to save the T-Statistic as well but I am having a hard time finding the right syntax to enter for the select function.

Here is the current function.

```
models <- lapply(paste(factors, ' ~  a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h+ j -',factors),
             function(f){ lm(as.formula(f), data = df) %>%               # Call lm(.)
                 summary() %>%                               # Gather the output
                 "$"(coef) %>%                               # Keep only the coefs
                 data.frame() %>%                            # Convert to dataframe
                 filter(rownames(.) == "(Intercept)") %>%    # Keep only the Intercept
                 dplyr::select(Estimate,`Pr...t..`)})         # Keep the coef & p-value
```

I know that I have to change the very last part of the function: `` dplyr::select(Estimate,`Pr...t..`) `` but after all my research and trial and error I am still stuck.

Here is a reproducible example using the mtcars data.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars

df <- df %>% 
  select(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

factors <- c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", "wt")

models <- lapply(paste(factors, ' ~  mpg + cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt -',factors),
                 function(f){ lm(as.formula(f), data = df) %>%               # Call lm(.)
                     summary() %>%                               # Gather the output
                     "$"(coef) %>%                               # Keep only the coefs
                     data.frame() %>%                            # Convert to dataframe
                     filter(rownames(.) == "(Intercept)") %>%    # Keep only the Intercept
                     dplyr::select(Estimate,`Pr...t..`)}         # Keep the coef & p-value
)


final <- matrix(unlist(models), ncol = 2, byrow = T) %>%       # Switch from list to dataframe
  data.frame(row.names = factors
```

Comment: Have you tried ```Pr(>|t|)```?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your help @RuiBarradas. I tried that and get the error that the column doesn't exist. When I try 't value' I get the same error

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example or structure of `models`?

Comment: @NadPat Thank you for your help. I edited my original post to include a reproducible example

Comment: works for me ... ?

Comment: If you have the p value and the degrees of freedom, you can use: `qt(p,de)` to calculate your t value.  You just have to see whether you need two tails or a single tail.  The command is pretty straight forward and the documentation in R is quite clear.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me. You can make this a little bit more "tidy" as follows:

```r
library(broom)

sumfun <- function(f) {
  lm(as.formula(f), data = df) %>%          
    tidy() %>%
    filter(term == "(Intercept)") %>%
    dplyr::select(estimate, p.value)
}
pp <- paste(factors, ' ~  mpg + cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt -',factors)
names(pp) <- factors
final <- purrr::map_dfr(pp, sumfun, .id = "factor")
```